# Querying foreign table with SP-GiST index results in "ERROR: cache lookup failed for type 0"

Tags: postgresql, index, postgis, foreign-data

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.3 (compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit) and I want to access a table in another Postgres database using **postgres_fdw** but since the original table has an **SP-GiST** index on a geometry column, the query on the foreign table fails with "ERROR:  cache lookup failed for type 0", even if the table is empty.

Does anyone knows how to query the foreign table without throwing the error and still keeping the SP-GiST index on the remote table?

Here's a sample SQL to reproduce the error:

1. Create remote database:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE remote
       WITH 
       OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
   ```
2. Create local database:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE localdb
       WITH 
       OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
   ```
3. Setup remote database (connect to 'remote' database before running the following SQL):

   ```
   CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
   CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;

   CREATE SCHEMA remote;

   CREATE TABLE remote.locations
   (
       id bigserial NOT NULL UNIQUE,
       name character varying,
       lonlat geometry NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
   ) 
   WITH (
       OIDS = FALSE
   );
   CREATE INDEX remote_locations_lonlat_idx
       ON remote.locations USING spgist
       (lonlat);
   ```
4. Setup local database (connect to 'localdb' database before running the following SQL):

   ```
   CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
   CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;

   CREATE SCHEMA localdb;

   CREATE SERVER remote FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'localhost', dbname 'remote', port '5432', extensions 'postgis');
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER remote OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'YOUR_POSTGRES_USER_PASSWORD');

   IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA remote FROM SERVER remote INTO localdb OPTIONS (import_not_null 'true');
   ```
5. Querying the foreign table...

   ```
   SELECT * from localdb.locations;
   ```
6. ...results in:

   ```
   ERROR:  cache lookup failed for type 0
   CONTEXT:  remote SQL command: SELECT id, name, lonlat FROM remote.locations
   SQL state: XX000
   ```

Comment: Do you get the same error message if you execute that SQL command directly on the remote database?

Comment: Replying to @LaurenzAlbe, I don't get the error if I run "SELECT * from remote.locations;" on the 'remote' database. I also don't get the error if the remote table doesn't have the index.

Comment: Try to create a reproducible test case and report it as a PostgreSQL bug.

Comment: What version of PostGis?  How did you install PostgreSQL and PostGis?  (compile from source, or use which package manager and which repo?)

Comment: @jjanes I'm using a windows server machine. I used the installers: "postgresql-11.3-1-windows-x64.exe" and "postgis-bundle-pg11x64-setup-2.5.2-1.exe"

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe. I've just submitted the report to the "pgsql-bugs@lists.postgresql.org" bug report mailing list, where I included a link to this question.

Comment: Following advice from the reply I've got from [PostgresSQL community](https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Querying-foreign-table-with-SP-GiST-index-results-in-ERROR-cache-lookup-failed-for-type-0-td6090679.html), I've changed the index type from **spgist** to **gist** and it's working.